# How to use the "description" to find out the "name" of Java Enum

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Test {
    a("This is a"),
    b("This is b"),
    c("This is c"),
    d("This is d");

    private final String type;

    Test(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
         return type;
    }
}
```

The above is my simple code. Could someone teach me how to get the name via using desc?
For example: I have a String "This is c", and I want to use this String to get Test.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use enum's `values` method , iterate it, you can get it.

```
public enum Test {
    a("This is a"),
    b("This is b"),
    c("This is c"),
    d("This is d");

    private final String type;

    Test(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
         return type;
    }

    public static Test getByDesc(String desc){
      for(Test t : Test.values()){
        if(t.getType().equals(desc)){
          return t;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: i would go with Jon Skeet's solution, you dont want to iterate over all values on each call...

Comment: @A4L yes, in the production env we adopt Jon Skeet's solution.

Comment: @donnior, cool! for beginers is your answer easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do this frequently, you'd want to build up a map from type (you don't have anything in the code called "description") to `Test`. For example:

```
// Within Test
private static final Map<String, Test> typeMap = createTypeMap();

private static Map<String, Test> createTypeMap() {
    Map<String, Test> ret = new HashMap<String, Test>();
    for (Test test : Test.values()) {
        ret.put(test.type, test);
    }
    return ret;
}

public static Test fromType(String type) {
    return typeMap.get(type);
}
```

Comment: This code maybe better architecture, but it is much difficult understanding for some newbies like me :(

Comment: @YeungKaSing: Well which part don't you understand? Do you understand maps?

Comment: I heart Map before but never meet, dose the Map.get() will loop all the type that put before too?

Comment: @YeungKaSing: Well it depends on the implementation - but `HashMap` uses a hash-based lookup which is O(1)... very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This method will return enum type based on enumvalue

```
public static Test getEnum(String enumValue) {

        for (Test c : Test.values()) {

            if (c.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase(enumValue))

                return c;

        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Same answer as the first reply, so I accept the quicker one :) Anyway, thank you.